# What should I write in the baseline URL field of magento 1.4.2.0 while installing on WAMP server?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

`http://localhost/magento/` is what comes in that field by default in the configuration step, but when I click proceed it throws and error.
Ican't even leave it blank, so what should I write there and what is it for?

Comment: In addition to the suggestion to use 127.0.0.1 be aware that you can also get errors if url rewriting isn't working like it should after you attempt to log in.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well documented problem. Magento doesn't like "localhost" and prefers "127.0.0.1" instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should have dots in you url to make it usable in Magento. So you can add some domain name in